# Help with dual of a problem

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow, duality, dual

Could anyone confirm me if I write the correct dual for my problem? The different sets confuse me a lot.

[image]
$s$ is the source node and $t$ the sink node.
[image]

I'm uncertain if the last dual constraint in necessary.

Comment: Please use MathJax.  You have a typo ($A3$ instead of $A^3$).  Also, your primal problem doesn't mention $A^4$ anywhere.  And do you have lower bounds $X_a \ge 0$?

Comment: Sorry that I missed the $A3$. $A^4$ is part of $A$, but is not in the objective function. It's in the "Notice that".

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification. Two more typos: $x$ should be $X$, and $X_e$ should be $X_a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks almost correct to me.  Two issues:

- Your $ \le$ dual constraints suggest that you omitted $X_a \ge 0$ in the primal.  If instead $X_a$ is free, then your dual constraints should be $=$.
- Your Tail and Head are reversed in the dual.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spend two whole week fighting with this! My first time with a model like this with so many subsets.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.  Also, you might find Arthur Benjamin's [S-O-B Method](https://math.hmc.edu/benjamin/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2019/06/Sensible-Rules-for-Remembering-Duals%E2%80%93The-S-O-B-Method.pdf) useful.